# Let $I = (0, 1)$ and let P be a polynomial of degree 2. Find a specific polynomial $P(x)$ such that $P(I)$={$P(x) : x ∈ I$} is an open interval.

Tags: polynomials, continuity

I also need to find a specific polynomial such that $P(x)$ is a half-open interval and a closed interval, if that exists.

I'm wondering if I could just do $P(x)=x^2$ for the first part. Since $0<x<1$, $P(x)$ would also be on the interval $(0,1)$, right?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, could you please tag it as homework?

Comment: Yep...you're on the right track. Now you have two more tasks to work out.

Comment: The "homework" tag is long gone.

Comment: yeah it wouldn't let me tag it as homework.

Comment: @JohnHughes  how could we map from the open interval $(0,1)$ to a half open interval? More specifically, how do we go from an open interval $(x,y)$ to a closed interval $[x,y]$? I'm confused about how it would be closed at one point. I'm thinking about polynomials like $(x-.5)^2$? But, it would be closed at y=0 and it would still be defined at y=1. We can't create an asymptote with just a polynomial, can we?

Comment: No, you can't create an asymptote with just a polynomial. And $(x-0.5)^2$ does indeed have the characteristics you described, so you're even further along. The only question remaining is the "closed interval"...and I'm going to let you think about that, and about why what you wrote for the half-open interval worked.

Comment: Oh. So $(x-0.5)^2$ is a half-open interval. Then, $P(I)=(0,.25]$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** The image of a quadratic polynomial $P:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ on an open interval $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is

- never a closed set;
- an open set if and only if $P$ is monotonic on $I$.

Of course, $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the standard topology.